# Write dictionaries with different keys to CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I've got some dictionaries:

```
d1 = {'name':'jon','age':4}
d2 = {'name':'joe','age':34,'height':100}
```

I have other dictionaries not listed here, with some different keys, but they have some keys in common with `d1` and `d2`.

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'a') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f) 
    wr.writerow(d1.values())
    wr.writerow(d2.values())
```

Of course, this does not put the data in the right columns. It does not make the headers needed either. How do I set this up so that every key from every dictionary becomes a header, and the values are put in the right places when writing the info to the CSV?

Comment: Do you use pandas in your project?

Comment: @adirabargil no

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=csv_columns)` instead of `csv.writer(f)` check out the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). As for the `csv_columns` if you don't know beforehand all the column names you can loop through all the dictionaries find the unique ones and add them to the list.

I wrote an example below.

```py
import csv

d1 = {'name':'jon', 'age':4}
d2 = {'name':'joe', 'age':34, 'height':100}

csv_columns = ['name', 'age', 'height']

with open('file.csv', 'a') as f:
    wr = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=csv_columns)
    wr.writeheader()
    wr.writerow(d1)
    wr.writerow(d2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to handle this is to create a class that keeps track of all the dicts that you add to it and then write the file for you.

This class will allow you to add as many dicts as you want and will keep track of all the fields and add those to file appropriately.

```
class CsvDictWriter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dicts = []
        self.fields = set()

    def add_dict(self, obj: dict):
        self.dicts.append(obj)
        self.fields.update(obj.keys())

    def write(self, file_name: str):
        with open(file_name, 'w') as fp:
            dw = DictWriter(fp, self.fields, restval='')
            dw.writeheader()
            for obj in self.dicts:
                dw.writerow(obj)


d1 = {'name': 'jon', 'age': 4}
d2 = {'name': 'joe', 'age': 34, 'height': 100}

cdw = CsvDictWriter()
cdw.add_dict(d1)
cdw.add_dict(d2)
cdw.write('file.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a list of all possible keys and the order in which you want them written to the csv. You won't be able to build the file "on the fly" as you won't know which keys, and in what order, each dictionary contains; unless you inspect all the dictionaries before you start writing them to the file.

Using the list of headers (keys) and a [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) you can then work your way through each one and output to the file.

The DiscWriter class parameters has a `restval`, you will need this as not all your dictionaries have all keys. It is described as:

> The optional restval parameter specifies the value to be written if the dictionary is missing a key in fieldnames.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be not very performant, but it should work without needing to know the names of all columns.  This generates a tab separated csv string.  The results can be easily written to a file

```
def exportArrayDicToCSV(arrayDict):
csvData = {}
headerString = ''
bodyString = ''
print(f"Processing Dictionary List")
for rowDataIndex in range(0, len(arrayDict)):
    print(f"{rowDataIndex + 1} out of {len(arrayDict)} rows processed")
    rowData = arrayDict[rowDataIndex]
    for header in rowData:
        if header not in csvData:
            csvData[header] = [""] * len(arrayDict)
        csvData[header][rowDataIndex] = rowData[header]
        
headerList = list(csvData.keys())
headerString = "\t".join(headerList)

print(f"generating CSV string")
for rowDataIndex in range(0, len(arrayDict)):
    print(f"{rowDataIndex + 1} out of {len(arrayDict)} rows processed")
    rowDataString = ''
    for fieldIndex in range(0, len(headerList)):
        rowDataString = f"{rowDataString}{csvData[headerList[fieldIndex]][rowDataIndex]}"
        if fieldIndex < len(headerList) - 1:
            rowDataString = f"{rowDataString}\t"
        
    bodyString = f"{bodyString}{rowDataString}"
    if rowDataIndex < len(arrayDict)-1:
        bodyString = f"{bodyString}\n"
return f"{headerString}\n{bodyString}"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).